# Group by join query

Tags: sql

I have the following 3 tables.

Student(**snum**: integer, sname: string, major: string, level: string, age: integer).

Class(**name**: string, meets_at: time, room: string)

Enrolled(**snum**: integer, **cname**: string)

I want to get the the number of classes that a student is enrolled and the name of the earliest class that the student is enrolled in. How would I do this in a single SQL query?

```
SELECT S.sname, COUNT(*), MIN(C.meets_at)
FROM Student S, Class C, Enrolled E
WHERE S.snum=E.snum and C.name=E.cname 
GROUP BY S.snum
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to get the name of the class.

Comment: Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Comment: Ok, I've added what I've tried so far.

Comment: HAVE YOU FIGURE IT OUT?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count of classes that student with snum 1 is enrolled in:

```
select count(*) from enrolled where snum = 1;
```

Earliest class for student with snum 1 (SQL is somewhat database specific - a;; backends do not use the same functions and or taking result set. ie: with MS SQL server)

```
select top 1 cname from enrolled e 
  inner join class c on c.name = e.cname
  where e.snum = 1 and c.meets_at >= cast(getdate() as time)
  order by meets_at
```